# Failure delivering result ResultInfo to activity when selecting a photo from Google photos app

Tags: android, android-intent

I get this crash when selecting trying to pick an image from the new Google Photo's app

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/20639/ACTUAL flg=0x1 (has clip) }} to activity {com.tyczj.xxx/com.tyczj.xxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3432)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
            at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:467)
            at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:457)
            at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:429)
            at com.tyczj.xxx.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:537)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5446)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3428)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the Intent I use

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, IMAGE_PICK);
```

I only get the crash with the Google Photo's app. If I use the built in gallery it works fine.

is this a bug with the new Photo's app or is there something else I have to do for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it is a bug with the new google photos app. The new update rolling (version 1.0.1) fixes this problem